# Call ambiguous between methods that return different types when the return type is explicit

Tags: c#, ambiguous-call

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question about ambiguous calls in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887044/question-about-ambiguous-calls-in-c-sharp)

I have these two methods:

```
TypeA MyMethod(string s) {}
TypeB MyMethod(string s) {}
```

The following call gives me "ambiguity between methods" error:

```
TypeA ta = MyMethod("some string");
```

How does this happen when I'm asking for a `TypeA` object to return explicitly and not via `var` or otherwise?

---

`TypeA` and `TypeB` are separate classes, they don't have anything in common.

Comment: Because the function accepts a string, and its the same name so its ambiguous.

Comment: How do you have those two methods to start with? You shouldn't be able to overload like that. Please give a short but *complete* example where the only thing that fails to compile is the *call* to the method.

Comment: TypeA and TypeB will always have Object as a common base class.

Comment: Because return type is not a part of method signature.

Comment: @Hamlet well, it is. IL supports it - C# does not.

Comment: @MarcGravell, Thanks. IL supports much more things...

Comment: This question is not about IL, it's about C#. In the terminology used by the C# specification, return type is _not_ a part of the method signature. What is important here is than in C# the return type never has any relevance when resolving which overload to call. And return type is also irrelevant for determining if it's allowed to have two "identical" methods inside the same type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the C# spec v4.0, section 1.6.6:

> The signature of a method must be unique in the class in which the
>   method is declared. The signature of a method consists of the name of
>   the method, the number of type parameters and the number, modifiers,
>   and types of its parameters. The signature of a method does not
>   include the return type.

You have two methods with the same signature because they differ only in the return type. This is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overload return types ,  if you are calling the method in this way

```
TypeA ta = MyMethod("some string");
```

then it would obvious to the compiler to pick a method.But what happens if you call it in this way

```
MyMethod("some string");
```

you are not using the value returned by the method,then the compiler will not be able to pick an appropriate method to call, this why it is an ambiguous call